# Backport Java 8 Lambda code - JSON byte array to Avro

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, avro

I need to backport some Java 8 code from this library:
https://github.com/allegro/json-avro-converter

Could someone more experienced with Java 8 confirm whether the following code for converting JSON encoded byte arrays to an Avro  is effectively identical, and that there isn't a silly edge case I've missed?

With lambdas:

```
private GenericData.Record readRecord(Map<String,Object> json, Schema schema, Deque<String> path) {
    GenericRecordBuilder record = new GenericRecordBuilder(schema);

    json.entrySet().forEach(entry ->
        ofNullable(schema.getField(entry.getKey()))
            .ifPresent(field -> record.set(field, read(field, field.schema(), entry.getValue(), path, false))));
    return record.build();
}
```

My modifications for JDK7:

```
private GenericData.Record readRecord(Map<String,Object> json, Schema schema, Deque<String> path) {
    GenericRecordBuilder record = new GenericRecordBuilder(schema);

    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : json.entrySet()) {
        Schema.Field field = schema.getField(entry.getKey());
        if (field != null) {
            record.set(field, read(field, field.schema(), entry.getValue(), path, false));
        }
        else {
          // Do nothing
        }
    }
    return record.build();
}
```

Comment: This type of question might be better suited for codereview.

Comment: Looks accurate to me. The `else` block is obviously superfluous. Why is this tagged with [tag:retrolambda]?

Comment: Is this not what tests are for?